# is there way to return Text and View together ? because it doesn't work for me

Tags: javascript, azure, react-native, expo, jsx

This is my example of return jsx elements inside the loadingMessage.

```
return (
        <AzureLoginView
          azureInstance={this.azureInstance}
          loadingMessage={
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, fontWeight: "bold" }}>loding data</Text>
```

> Here it doesn't let me put my view inside the loadingMessage as listed below and I don't understand why.

```
        <View style={styles.appBottomMainContainer}>
          <View style={styles.appBottomView}>
            <Text>{'\u00A9'}Developed by Mobile Team</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      }
      onSuccess={this._onLoginSuccess}
    />)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs it states AzureLoginView loadingMessage should be a string rather than a JSX component. So try instead with that.

But in future , for any other components , yes you can return JSX components like FlatList uses it, Like thr one in renderItem :

```
<FlatList
        data={this.props.tripsReducer.trips}
        renderItem={({item, index}) => {
          return (<View><Text>{item}</Text></View>);
        }}
      />
```

Comment: i dont understand, can you show me how to do in my example ?

Comment: in your just add this loadingMessages = "loading wait.."